# Can an electromagnetic wave be represented separately or it requires both electric and magnetic field for its representation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Let us consider that electric field wave propagates through xy plane and magnetic field wave propagates through yz plane. So does that mean the electromagnetic wave is propagating through a plane which is exactly in between the xy and yz plane or it is impossible to represent EM wave in that way?

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic waves are solutions of Maxwell's equations. Before their definition one just talked of "light", no electric and magnetic field knowledge.

[image: emwave]

> [Electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This 3D animation shows a plane linearly polarized wave propagating from left to right. The electric and magnetic fields in such a wave are in-phase with each other, reaching minima and maxima together.

The values on the perpendicular planes are the size of the electric in one plane and magnetic in the other, the **whole** is the electromagnetic wave, this is a representation of the mathematical functions that make it up.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I thought these two waves resulted in a third wave which propagates through a plane exactly in between them